# How do I pick the sum of two columns using the query function

Tags: pandas

Because I find myself typing the following patterns frequently in Pandas

```
(dataframe['colA'] / dataframe['colB']).describe()
```

I am trying to do this using the more succinct query function.

```
dataframe.query("colA / colB").describe()
```

Unfortunately, the usage above does not work. 
Any suggestions to get it working?

Comment: Why do you think `df.query('colA / colB')` is better than `df.colA/df.colB`  ? Any particular reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `query` for this.

On the other hand, you could use [`eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html):

```
In [63]: df = pd.DataFrame({"colA": [1,2,3], "colB": [3,4,5]})

In [64]: df.eval("colA / colB")
Out[64]: 
0    0.333333
1    0.500000
2    0.600000
dtype: float64

In [65]: df.eval("colA / colB").describe()
Out[65]: 
count    3.000000
mean     0.477778
std      0.134715
min      0.333333
25%      0.416667
50%      0.500000
75%      0.550000
max      0.600000
dtype: float64
```

but honestly I don't think this pattern is as convenient as you may think it's going to be.  YMMV, of course.